# How to replace a build in relationship field by a flexrelate field

Tags: sugarcrm

For example in Opportunities and Cases there are relationship fields directly pointing to accounts. I have a custom module that integrates into those modules. I could add a separate relate field for the custom module, but what I want is a flexrelate allowing only Accounts and the Custom module. This works fine by setting a special options list in the parent_name. but results in a parent_type and parent_id field in db.

How do I configure the flexrelate so that on selecting accounts as parent_type it save to account_id and on selecting the custom module it saves to it's id field?

The options for the flexrelate:

```
$app_list_strings['parent_type_display_custom']['CustomMod'] = 'CustomMod';
$app_list_strings['parent_type_display_custom']['Accounts'] = 'Accounts';
$app_list_strings['record_type_display_custom']['CustomMod'] = 'CustomMod';
$app_list_strings['record_type_display_custom']['Accounts'] = 'Accounts';
```

The additional vardefs for Cases:

```
$dictionary["Case"]["fields"]["parent_type"] = array (
  'name' => 'parent_type',
  'type' => 'link',
            'vname' => 'LBL_PARENT_TYPE',
            'type' => 'parent_type',
            'dbType' => 'varchar',
            'group' => 'parent_name',
            'options' => 'parent_type_display_custom',
            'len' => '255',

        );
$dictionary["Case"]["fields"]['parent_name'] =
        array(
            'name' => 'parent_name',
            'parent_type' => 'record_type_display',
            'type_name' => 'parent_type',
            'id_name' => 'parent_id', 
            'vname' => 'LBL_RELATED_TO',
            'type' => 'parent(_custom)',
            'source' => 'non-db',
            'options' => 'record_type_display_custom',
        );
$dictionary["Case"]["fields"]['parent_id'] =
        array(
            'name' => 'parent_id',
            'vname' => 'LBL_PARENT_ID',
            'type' => 'id',
            'required' => false,
            'reportable' => true,
            'comment' => 'eighter the Id of an account or a custommodule'
        );
```

Comment: As I see now I should write a special SugarField for this purpose. It's kind of hard to figure out how to modify the EditView.tpl.  Now I wonder if I should just write a js that kind of copies the ids into the right fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this SugarCRM developer blog post help?

http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2011/05/16/howto-create-a-flex-relate-for-other-modules/

Comment: Looks promising. I'll give it a try next week. Many thanks John. I should search deeper next time ;-)